# Need to parse a string so each individual element can be compared to an element in another string

Tags: java, string, parsing, bufferedreader

I am trying to parse the text from a file that reads "This is a test. This is a simple test." I need to parse it so I can compare it to another file which is a dictionary. This is apart of a spell check program. I am having troubles implementing a r.readline and r.split methods.

```
    String fileName2 = "test.txt";
    String line2 = null;
    String[] diction2 = new String [100];


    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader2 = 
            new FileReader(fileName2);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader2);
        int j=0;
        while((line = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            diction2[j]=line;
            System.out.println(diction2[j]);
             j++;
             //r.readline(line);
             //delimiter
             //r.split

             //need to parse line to get each individual word out and compare to dictionary
        }    

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader2.close();            
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");                   
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: where is split method?

Comment: What is the type of the variable 'r'?

Comment: What problems are you having, i.e. what does it do vs. what do you want it to do?

Comment: I have read the files in, I just need to parse the words so instead of them printing out on one line, they are printed out vertically in order, and being able to compare each word to the words in my dictionary file

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

when you do:

```
for(String word : words){
    //Do some action
}
```

it means that it will take each string inside the "words" array, one by one, store it inside "word" and execute the "Do some action" for it.

it is the same as writing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    String word = words[i];
    //Do something
}
```

**End of edit.**

As here:

```
while((line = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {
```

You are already reading the line, can't you just do:

```
String fileName2 = "test.txt";
String line = null;
String[] diction2 = new String [100];


try {
    // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
    FileReader fileReader2 = 
        new FileReader(fileName2);

    // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
    BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = 
        new BufferedReader(fileReader2);
    int j=0;
    while((line = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println(line);
        diction2[j]=line;
        System.out.println(diction2[j]);
         j++;
         //There you get the list of all the words in the line
         String[] words = line.split(" ");
         for(String word : words){
             //Check your word here
         }
    }    

    // Always close files.
    bufferedReader2.close();            
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println(
        "Unable to open file '" + 
        fileName + "'");                
}
catch(IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(
        "Error reading file '" 
        + fileName + "'");                   
    // Or we could just do this: 
    // ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I have never seen the string word : words format, what is the purpose of that?

Comment: OK thank you, I will dabble around with it when I get more time.